# Calculate difference between two values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with 'count' column

```
ID    count  OperationID 
100   111      1
99    55       1
94    55       1
90    66       1 
100   69       2
99    33       2
94    33       2
90    47       2
100   777      3
99    55       3
94    31       3
90    12       3
```

I need calculate difference between two Id's counts. Need to compare ID's and values for this ID's. Ex. compare ID 100 and ID 99. EX. for ID 100 > count for ID 99 (111 > 55) show 56(difference between two values). for ID 99 > count for ID 94 (55 = 55) show 0 etc.. How can I do that?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select operation_id, (t100.count - t99.count) as diff
from t t100 join
     t t99
     on t100.operation_id = t99.operation_id and
        t100.id = 100 and t99.id = 99;
```

If you just want the difference with the "previous" value for all rows, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (t.count - lag(t.count) over (partition by t.operation_id order by t.id)) as diff
from t;
```

Comment: I think OP want the second one, just `ORDER BY t.id DESC`

Comment: Nearly. But I need compare other id's also. ID 100 compare with ID 99, ID 99 compare with ID 94. ID 94 compare with 90...etc.

Comment: `LAG` is [2012+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) in case OP was wondering.

Comment: @Kiriil . . . Just do the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cross Apply with a clause:

```
    Create table #test ([ID] int, [count] int, [OperationID] int)

    insert into #test values(100, 111, 1)
    insert into #test values(99 , 55 , 1)
    insert into #test values(94 , 55 , 1)
    insert into #test values(90 , 66 , 1) 
    insert into #test values(100, 69 , 2)
    insert into #test values(99 , 33 , 2)
    insert into #test values(94 , 33 , 2)
    insert into #test values(90 , 47 , 2)
    insert into #test values(100, 777, 3)
    insert into #test values(99 , 55 , 3)
    insert into #test values(94 , 31 , 3)
    insert into #test values(90 , 12 , 3)

    select t1.[OperationID], t1.[ID], t2.[ID], t1.count, t2.count, t1.count - t2.count as Diff
    from #test t1
    cross apply #test t2
    where t1.OperationID = t2.OperationID and t1.ID <> t2.ID
    order by t1.OperationID, t1.[ID], t2.[ID]
```

Comment: why cross apply, I believe we may use inner join also which would return same result set

Comment: @piyushjain It is the same thing in this case with the where clauses. When comparing all sides it seemed intrinsic to use cross join. The execution plan won't discern.